# onclick listener how to call another acitivity

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener

How do I call another activity in the following code?

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check if next song is there or not
            s2=val.size();  

            if(++s1>=s2){               
            s1=0;           

            }else{

                uri2=tid.get(s1);
                System.out.println("tid=="+uri2);

                uri1=val.get(s1);
                uri = uri1.replace(" ", "%20");             
                url="http://192.168.0.5/music/songs/mp3/"+uri;  
                playSong(url);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to start another activity something in `onClick(View arg0)` right? You need to create a new intent, and then use the intent to start the new activity. Make sure you define the new activity in your android manifest. Check out this link. It should help a lot.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: no i want play pause next previous options are there in one activity. these all are the functionaltys i want to cal my entire activitys how?